# Azure AD custom claim as separate attribute values

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, claims

I am using an extension attribute in AAD to store some custom claims that I need to send back to ADFS via an SSO Ent app. I need these claims to be separate values (see screenshot)
The problem I have is that the [data type of the extension attribute is string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0)

You can't create a new extension attribute as datatype collection, but even if that was possible it wouldn't work: I tested using an existing field (OtherMail) which is a collection, and only one value is returned as claim

Can I pass this custom claim to my ent app without relying on the extension attributes, or is that the only way the ent app can then pass this token to ADSF?

[image: ribute [![][2]]]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple custom claim in the extension.
create a separate claim for each attribute and pass it accordingly.
Just try to go with 2 attribute initially and if it is working, you can go with multiple attributes based on your requirement.

Verify the application as well whether it is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) or not.

Comment: I can have up to 200 attributes values (the number varies every time), means I would need to create 200 custom attributes and claims, which doesn't seem to be a good way to implement this. I would need to be able to pass the 200 values in one claim attribute